# How to integrate Iamport korean payment gateway?

Tags: android, android-studio, payment

I have created one app. Now i want to integrate [Iamport](http://www.iamport.kr/) korean payment getaway in my app. I have read the whole [documentation](http://www.iamport.kr/getstarted) on developer portal. I have checked [example](https://github.com/iamport/iamport-inicis-android) code which is already in `github` but i am still not getting exact solution.

**Problem:-**
I am not getting that how to integrate with my app, because in that demo there is only one `URL`. Means i am not getting exact flow of payment gateway. can anyone give solution step by step. so i can understand perfectly. i am trying to implement this last 2 weeks and now i stucked.

I done the following code.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.zennaxx.iamportpay.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mainWebView;
    private static final String APP_SCHEME = "iamporttest://";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super . onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        mainWebView . setWebViewClient ( new  InicisWebViewClient ( this ));
        WebSettings settings = mainWebView . getSettings ();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager . setAcceptCookie ( true );
            cookieManager . setAcceptThirdPartyCookies (mainWebView, true );
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri intentData = intent.getData();

        if ( intentData == null ) {
            mainWebView.loadUrl("myUrl");
        } else {
            // When returning after payment follow-up Certification isp
            String url = intentData.toString();
            if ( url.startsWith(APP_SCHEME) ) {
                String redirectURL = url.substring(APP_SCHEME.length()+3);
                mainWebView.loadUrl(redirectURL);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected  void  onNewIntent ( Intent  intent ) {
        String url = intent.toString();
        if ( url.startsWith(APP_SCHEME) ) {
            String redirectURL = url.substring(APP_SCHEME.length()+3);
            mainWebView.loadUrl(redirectURL);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read perfectly then already specified in that stets how to integrate payment gateway.

Let me explain you everything step by step ::

> Step-1 ::

Go with this first [URL](https://admin.iamport.kr/) and create your own account and login.
then you will get `API KEY` and `API SECRET KEY` and then after open `PG setting (authentication method payment)` tab and keep it on your `SendBox` (ON means your payment gateway is on testing mode and OFF means your payment gateway is live).

> Step-2 ::

Copy IamPort SDK from [HERE](https://github.com/iamport/iamport-inicis-android/tree/master/src/com/siot) and integrate with your project.

> Step-3 ::

Put this code as it :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mainWebView;
    private static final String APP_SCHEME = "iamporttest://";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super . onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        mainWebView . setWebViewClient ( new  InicisWebViewClient ( this ));
        WebSettings settings = mainWebView . getSettings ();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager . setAcceptCookie ( true );
            cookieManager . setAcceptThirdPartyCookies (mainWebView, true );
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri intentData = intent.getData();

        if ( intentData == null ) {
            //payment.html file is below
            mainWebView.loadUrl("https://yourdomain/API/payment.html");

        } else {
            // When returning after payment follow-up Certification isp
            String url = intentData.toString();
            if ( url.startsWith(APP_SCHEME) ) {
                String redirectURL = url.substring(APP_SCHEME.length()+3);
                mainWebView.loadUrl(redirectURL);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected  void  onNewIntent ( Intent  intent ) {
        String url = intent.toString();
        if ( url.startsWith(APP_SCHEME) ) {
            String redirectURL = url.substring(APP_SCHEME.length()+3);
            mainWebView.loadUrl(redirectURL);
        }
    }

}
```

> Step-4 ::

Override `onPageFinished()` Method like this and make related changes after read below code.

```
public class InicisWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    public static final String TAG = "[InicisWebViewClient]";

    private Activity activity;


    String imp_uid = "", merchant_uid = "", imp_success = "", error_msg = "", paymentStatusRecUrl = "",
         apply_num = "";

    public InicisWebViewClient(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("javascript:"))
        {
            Intent intent = null;

            try {
                //Intent URI process
                Log.e(TAG, "in side try block...");
                intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(intent.getDataString());

                //Run the appropriate Activity
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
                return true;
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                return false;
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                if ( intent == null )
                    return false;

                // Pre-processing for non-installed apps (such as moving Google Play)
                if ( handleNotFoundPaymentScheme(intent.getScheme()) )
                    return true;



                String packageName = intent.getPackage();
                if (packageName != null) {
                    // If you have packageName, search on Google Play
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }


        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param scheme
     * @return Whether to process the scheme directly
     * 
     * Processes if ActivityNotFoundException occurs because 3rd party app for billing is not yet installed.
     * If you can extract package information from an intent for a scheme that is not handlered here, then move to market as packageName from the following.
     * 
     */
    protected boolean handleNotFoundPaymentScheme(String scheme) {

        //If you do not run the market after an ActivityNotFoundException occurs because there is no package information in the url that the PG calls
        if ( PaymentScheme.ISP.equalsIgnoreCase(scheme) ) {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + PaymentScheme.PACKAGE_ISP)));
            return true;
        } else if ( PaymentScheme.BANKPAY.equalsIgnoreCase(scheme) ) {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + PaymentScheme.PACKAGE_BANKPAY)));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        Log.e("[InicisWebViewClient]", "onPageFinished() url = " + url);

        String receivedFinishURL = url;

        String paymentStatusUrl = null;
        try {
            paymentStatusUrl = getDomainName(receivedFinishURL);
            Log.e(TAG, "paymentStatusUrl = " + paymentStatusUrl.toString());

            if (paymentStatusUrl.equals("https://yourdomain/API/paymentStatus.html")) // Write here redirected URL which you have set in JavaScript File
            {

                paymentStatusRecUrl = receivedFinishURL;
                List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(receivedFinishURL), "UTF-8");

                for (NameValuePair param : params) {
                    if ("imp_uid".equals(param.getName()))
                    {
                        imp_uid = param.getValue();
                    }
                    else if ("merchant_uid".equals(param.getName()))
                    {
                        merchant_uid = param.getValue();
                    }
                    else if ("imp_success".equals(param.getName()))
                    {
                        imp_success = param.getValue();
                    }
                    else if ("error_msg".equals(param.getName()))
                    {
                        error_msg = param.getValue();
                    }
                    else if ("apply_num".equals(param.getName()));
                    {
                        apply_num = param.getValue();
                    }
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "received paged data...........");
                Log.i(TAG, "imp_uid = " + imp_uid);
                Log.i(TAG, "merchant_uid = " + merchant_uid);
                Log.i(TAG, "imp_success = " + imp_success);
                Log.i(TAG, "error_msg = " + error_msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "apply_num = " + apply_num);

                if (imp_success.equals("true"))
                {
                    // If your payment will success then your cursore comes here
                   //if your payment is successful then you can start your new activity and design as per your requirement.
                }
                else if (imp_success.equals("false"))
                {
                    // If your payment will cancelled then your cursore comes here
                }



        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

> Step-5 ::

**payment.html**

you have to Implement your Script file like below but this is sample file you have to implement as per your requirement.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Payment Demo</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://service.iamport.kr/js/iamport.payment-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<style>
.goog-logo-link {
   display:none !important;
} 

.goog-te-gadget{
   color: transparent !important;
}
.goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo{color:#000 !important;}
</style>

<script>


function callme()
{
    IMP.init('yourIMPCredential');
    payRequest();
}
function payRequest()
{

    //you can set your value accordinglly by using simple domcument.getElementById().value
    IMP.request_pay({
    pg : 'inicis', // version 1.1.0.
    pay_method : 'card',
    merchant_uid : 'merchant_' + new Date().getTime(),
    name : 'This is My name',
    amount : 1000,
    buyer_email : 'this_is_buyer_email@gmail.com',
    buyer_name : 'This is buyer name',
    buyer_tel : '010-1234-5678',
    buyer_addr : 'This is buyer email',
    buyer_postcode : '123-456',
    m_redirect_url : 'https://yourdomain/API/payment.html'//here you can specified your URL
}, function(rsp) {
    if ( rsp.success ) {
        var msg = 'Succeess message.';
        msg += 'response_id: ' + rsp.imp_uid;
        msg += 'response_merchant_id : ' + rsp.merchant_uid;
        msg += 'response_paid_amount: ' + rsp.paid_amount;
        msg += 'rsp.apply_num: ' + rsp.apply_num;
    } else {
        var msg = 'Failure message.';
        msg += 'rsp.error_msg: ' + rsp.error_msg;
    }
    alert(msg);
});
}

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
  //goog-te-combo  
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="google_translate_element" style="text-align:center;"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" id="alertmsg"></div>
        <!-- panel preview -->
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4>I'mport; Payment module DEMO</h4>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <form name="frm" method="post" id="frm">
                <div class="panel-body form-horizontal payment-form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Payment Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="paymentName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="order_number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Order Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="order_number" name="order_number" value="1234">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ticket_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ticket Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ticket_name" name="ticket_name" value="ticket_1234">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Amount</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" value ="1000">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="buyer_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Buyer Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buyer_email" name="buyer_email" value="text@gmail.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="buyer_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Buyer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buyer_name" name="buyer_name" value="Tester">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="buyer_phone_number" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Buyer Phone Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="buyer_phone_number" name="buyer_phone_number" value="0129384756">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="buyer_tel" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Virtual account deposit date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="vbank_due" name="vbank_due">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button class='form-control btn btn-primary' type='submit' onclick="callme();"> Pay Now </button>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>            
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Create one another file where you can receive your payment status.

**paymentStaus.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Payment status</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script>
<style>

</style>

<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align:center;"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" id="alertmsg"></div>
        <!-- panel preview -->
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4>I'mport; Payment module Finish</h4>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <form name="frm" method="post" id="frm">
                <div class="panel-body form-horizontal payment-form">                                                      
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button class='form-control btn btn-primary' type='submit' > Finish </button>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>            
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Step-6 ::

If you need to check your payment by using API then check [here](https://api.iamport.kr/).
 Use `API_KEY` and `API SECRET_KEY`  for get token. Then after using that token and `imp_uid` number you will get all the detail of your payment.

I hope you will get your solution.May i know if you need anything.

Comment: 1+ Thank you so much for post this answer. It works charm.